# request module not fallowing redirect node.js

Tags: node.js, redirect, request

I'm trying to implement a web scraper using request module and node.js. Some time at the scrapping I must post a form and then It always redirect to somewhere else where I must reach to continue scraping.

```
var jarEstados = requestEstados.jar();

options = {
    url: urlPrincipal,
    method: 'POST',
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    followAllRedirect: true,
    jar: jarEstados,
    form: requestObject
};

requestEstados(options,function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(html);
    }
    else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Response:

```
<head><title>Object moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a HREF="Resumo_Por_Estado_Municipio.asp">here</a>.</body>

 headers:
 { 'cache-control': 'private',
   'content-length': '152',
   'content-type': 'text/html',
   location: 'Resumo_Por_Estado_Municipio.asp',
   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
   'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET, ARR/2.5, ASP.NET',
   'x-customname': 'ServidorANP',
   'x-ua-compatible': 'IE=7',
   date: 'Wed, 15 Jun 2016 16:08:42 GMT',
   connection: 'close' },
statusCode: 302,
```

the resquest doest fallow the redirect, even if configured as the module site said> [Resquest Module](https://github.com/request/request)

What am I doing wrong? Can't figure it out!

Comment: check the response status, moved is 302

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly Its 302, I did post the response headers above! What could I do in this case?

Comment: When 302 just cancel execution, you don't have control over external server tho, you can't do anything except parsing it's response and doing stuff according to status code

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Strange, because at the browser the request continues, without any user interaction. What could be the workarround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the job by myself. I figured out that if I pass some valid User-Agent using the 302 response I could manualy fallow the redirection and keep the train on the rails for the rest of the scrapping process.